# how to see contents of array in android studio

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, debugging

I have always had an issue with the way the android studio debugger displays array data. It's too confusing and not intuitive.

I'm having a problema with the addition of two custom objects into an array, where one of the variables is being overwritten when I try to render the contents.

I want to trace where that could be happening but having to see the contents of the array while in debugging mode is absolutely terrifying:

[image: I have no clue of what is going on here]

Is there a way to simplify stuff to an almost JSON-like state? Something like this:

```
Array:[
      {
        first object: {contents}
      },
      {
        secondobject: {contents}
      }
      ]
```

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do it like this using android studio debugging mode: [image]